# RowDataBound gridview selected color

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a `RowDataBound` with a `gridview` that looks for which year is active, now it has one and it's highlighted. But lets say I want to make another year active, the one is still highlighted, and the one you click on is also highlighted. but I want on

VB:

```
Protected Sub grdFinYear_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grdFinYear.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        If grdFinYear.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Values("FIN_ID") = FIN_ID Then
            Dim activeButton As Button = e.Row.FindControl("btnSelect")
            activeButton.CssClass = "ActionButtonsActiveYear"
            e.Row.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 121, 139, 169)
        Else
            Dim makeActiveButton As Button = e.Row.FindControl("btnSelect")
            makeActiveButton.CssClass = "ActionButtonsMakeThisYearActive"
        End If
    End If
    End Sub
```

C# or vb help is welcome, so I think its going to have to use like `selectedindexchange`. but then this `SUB` is half useless, no?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to fully understand.... but I think what you need to do when the year is changed you will need to rebind the grid this will run your rowdatabound code and change the highlights.

Comment: yeah, in the load of my form I set the FIN year to this year, so maybe there I can say if the year change to whatever then change the button and hilight. Does that soound right?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all your code it is hard to say... but yes on page load you set FIN year (do this only if not postback).

Amend your RowDataBound code to add some CommandName and  CommandArgument Attributes to the btnSelect like so...

```
Protected Sub grdFinYear_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grdFinYear.RowDataBound
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

    If grdFinYear.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Values("FIN_ID") = FIN_ID Then
        Dim activeButton As Button = e.Row.FindControl("btnSelect")
        activeButton.CssClass = "ActionButtonsActiveYear"
        activeButton.CommandName = "ActiveButton"
        activeButton.CommandArgument = **Bind to Year for this row**
        e.Row.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 121, 139, 169)
    Else
        Dim makeActiveButton As Button = e.Row.FindControl("btnSelect")
        makeActiveButton.CssClass = "ActionButtonsMakeThisYearActive"
        makeActiveButton.CommandName = "MakeActiveButton"
        makeActiveButton.CommandArgument = **Bind to Year for this row**
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Then in your code for btnSelect.click event...

```
Protected Sub btnSelect_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e as EventArgs) Handles btnSelect.Click
    If sender.CommandName = "MakeActiveButton" Then
        FIN = CInt(sender.CommandArgument)
        grdFIinYear.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope that Helps